# css to design breadcrumbs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following html code, I'm using bootstrap, here is my breadcrumb should look like.
[image]

I have created jsfiddle to style this, please check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4rubmwrw/)

Here is my html code

```
<div class="container">
                <ol class="list-inline">
                    <li class="done">
                        <div class="border_progress">
                         <span class="number">1</span>
                         <span class="text">Select your device to sell</span>                         </div>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <span class="number">1</span>
                         <span class="text">Select your device to sell</span>                        
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <span class="number">1</span>
                         <span class="text">Select your device to sell</span>                        
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
```

Here is my css

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.text, 
.number{
  color:white;
  background:green;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

I'm not getting how to create those arrows in between number and text. Any help suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

> https://jsfiddle.net/4rubmwrw/1/

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.text, .number{
  color:white;
  background:green;
  padding: 5px;
}

.number:after{
 content: '';
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 left: 4px;
 border-top: 8px solid transparent;
 border-left: 16px solid red;
 border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
                <ol class="list-inline">
                    <li class="done">
                        <div class="border_progress">
                         <span class="number">1</span>
                         <span class="text">Select your device to sell</span>                         </div>
                       
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <span class="number">1</span>
                         <span class="text">Select your device to sell</span>                        
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <span class="number">1</span>
                         <span class="text">Select your device to sell</span>                        
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
```